# Why can Uniform distribution be deduced from this indicator function?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, uniform-distribution

Given $f(X_1 \mid X_1 + X_2) \propto \mathbf{I}(X_1 \leq X_1 + X_2)$ where $\mathbf{I}()$ is the indicator function,
and $X_1, X_2$ are independent random variables following $expo(\theta)$ with $\theta \geq 0$

Why can it be deduced that $(X_1 \mid X_1 + X_2)  \sim U[0, X_1 + X_2]$ where $U$ is the uniform distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notations are highly confusing because $X_1$ on the lhs (of the density definition) should be a realisation (usually denoted by lower case $x_1$) while $X_1$ on the rhs is part of the conditioning rv $X_1+X_2$ (and should be set to an arbitrary realisation, $y$ say, even though $y=x_1+x_2$). I would thus rewrite the question as

> If $Y=X_1+X_2$ and the conditional distribution of $X_1$ conditional
> on $Y=y$ has density $$f(x_1|y)\propto\mathbb I(0\le x_1\le y)$$ what
> is the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $Y$?

The answer is then the Uniform $\mathcal U(0,y)$ distribution since the density is constant over its support, $[0,y]$.

Comment: Will you elaborate why the density being proportional to that indicator function results in a Uniform distribution? From what I understand shouldn't a density be $\frac{x}{b-a}$ for it to follow uniform[a, b]? Unless we multiply by and divide by the constant $\frac{1}{y-0}$?

Comment: It is the proportionality symbol where $y \propto x \Rightarrow y = ax$ for some constant $a$, will you answer my question?